# How to send a file res.send() along with some json data. The file must be downloaded on Postman side

Tags: node.js, json, file, response, xlsx

I have a excel file data and a callback with statuscode and message as (200 - mail sent)
I want to send download excel file as well as send res.json the json data(200 - mail sent).

I tried doing this

```
let ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(userData);
                        let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
                        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);
                        let userInfo = XLSX.write(wb, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: false });
```

Then after sending the userInfo to mail, i'm  sending callback like this

callback({ "statuscode": 200, "message": "Email sent successfully", "file": userInfo });
return;

or i can change it to

```
// callback({"status": {"statuscode": 200, "message": "Email sent successfully"},"file": userInfo });
                                // return;
```

Then in my controller, im sending it like this

```
router.post('/getUserInfoThroughExcel', function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    data.files = req.files;
    excel_controller.getUserInfoThroughExcel(data, function (response) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 'userData.xlsx');
        res.send(response.file)
    });
});
```

Now how can i send the statuscode & message with the file?

Im able to download file in postman (Send and Download), But i want to see the json response also

`res.json(response)`  -> The downloaded excel file from postman gets corrupted and no json data on response
`res.send(response)`  -> The downloaded excel file from postman gets corrupted and no json data on response
`res.send(response.file)`  -> The file is downloaded properly but json data must be included